# Add .OSM (OpenStreetMap) data to a QGIS project using python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I try to load a `.osm` file into my QGIS project using python.

So I've write this code:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

# Creation of the .osm file, the QuickOSM plugin is needed.
bbox = '795078.7779580103, 795572.1303964029, 5908035.195114954, 5908380.196820124'

alg_params = {
    'EXTENT': bbox,
    'KEY': 'highway',
    'SERVER': 'https://lz4.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter',
    'TIMEOUT': 25,
    'VALUE': ''
}
        
query = processing.run('quickosm:buildqueryextent', alg_params)
file = processing.run("native:filedownloader", {'URL':query['OUTPUT_URL'], 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

# Now I try to display the osm data:
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer(file['OUTPUT'], "lines", "ogr")
```

The code do not crash, but since an .osm file can contains several different geometry the `iface.addVectorLayer()` function open this windows:

[image]

And I need to manually select the geometry that I want to display (lines, multipolygons...). Is there a way to bypass this windows ? Is there a way to either load all the different geometry or to select the geometry that I'm interested in directly in the `iface.addVectorLayer()` function ?

Answer (score 6):

I've found a solution based on [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313333/load-lines-from-osm-in-processing-modeler/313360#313360)

It's possible to specify the geometry type by adding `|layername=my_geometry_type` to the file path.

So for example instead of using:

```
iface.addVectorLayer(r'C:/myfile.osm', "mylines", "ogr")
```

I can use

```
iface.addVectorLayer(r'C:/myfile.osm'+'|layername=lines', "mylines", "ogr")
```

To only load the lines.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You need to append the layer name to the file path. There is also in QuickOSM which will open all sublayers in your OSM file.

Answer (score 0):

your `'file'` is the .osm file that is the result of your query.

```
shp = processing.run('quickosm:openosmfile', {"FILE":file["OUTPUT"]})
```

`shp` will be a dictionary with the following values:

[image]

then we can store individual layers in different variables. example, here I'm storing the multipolygons of osm buildings in `buildingLyr`

```
buildingLyr = shp['OUTPUT_MULTIPOLYGONS']
```

and finally add that layer to QGIS

```
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(buildingLyr, 'OSM Buildings')
```