# Automatic download of OSM data via Graphical Modeler in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I am developing a script in the Graphic Modeler, allowing to download the data of a road network from OSM data, but I cannot recover them (for the polygon recovery it works well, on the other hand for the lines no)

[image]

Comment: You need to share more information, like the logs when you execute it, the modeler file maybe would help too, the query used in "réseau routier" ? Because with just this screenshot, there is not enough information to debug you.

Comment: I followed almost the same logic from this post(it worked to retrieve the polygons (Multipolygon), but not for a data network): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313333/load-lines-from-osm-in-processing-modeler/411092?noredirect=1#comment667580_411092

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would like to automate the download of OSM data via Modeleur graphic:
in this example I wanted to download a layer of a road network, and to do that I would have to filter the data, for having just the linear layers.

in the link that I have already put you they retrieve data and filter them to have polygons, it worked for me, but to filter linear data, it generates an empty layer for me

Comment: PLease do not add comments but edit your original post with more information, more structured question. Also, you still haven't provided us requested information mentioned : logs when executed, ... You can open the OSM file manually from your file browser and check the content.